# why are my python lambda functions not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm optimising my code for database filler from doc files and I'm doing it through replacing for loops with mapped lambda functions. And it was working, but then stopped. This example:

```
rawdata1 = sorted(map(lambda i: rawdata1.append(i.split('$$$')), rawdata))
# for i in rawdata:
#     rawdata1.append(i.split('$$$'))
```

shows the following error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

But when I uncomment for loop and comment lambda, all is fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `append` returns None. So you're passing a sequence of None to `sorted()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.append()` is an in place update, and returns `None`, so your current generator is creating a list of `None` which can't be compared by `sorted()`.

That aside, you don't need to keep track of your newly split items with `map()` as it's a generator that is being fed into `sorted()`.

Try:

```py
>>> my_list = ["a,a", "b,b", "c,c", "a,b"]
>>> sorted(map(lambda i: i.split(","), my_list))
[['a', 'a'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]
```

Or using a generator expression (my preferred method):

```py
>>> my_list = ["a,a", "b,b", "c,c", "a,b"]
>>> sorted(i.split(",") for i in my_list)
[['a', 'a'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]
```